# Checkbox to turn on/off GCM notification

Tags: android, checkbox, google-cloud-messaging

I done a lot researches but still not able to find any solution. I need to create a checkbox to choose whether receive GCM notification or not. I tried putting a global checkbox variable and while the checkbox.isChecked() equals to true, then will receive notification, vice versa. But the GCMIntentService class not allow me to modify the method. Appreciate for helps and sorry for my broken English.

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

```
public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

private static final String TAG = "===GCMIntentService===";

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    Log.i(TAG, "unregistered = " + arg1);
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "new message= ");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
        generateNotification(context, message);     
}

@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.icon;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreenActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

}

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity{

```
public static CheckBox chkBox;
ImageView img;
TextView t1,t2,t3,t4;

View v;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    this.getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.settings_actionbar_layout);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    chkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt3);
    t4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt4);
    v = (View)findViewById(R.id.line);

    t4.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:abc@abc.com\">Send Feedback</a>"));
    t4.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Comment: please add to the question, the preference layout that includes your checkbox you created.

Comment: @petey I'm not using preference layout nor CheckBoxPreference, just CheckBox in an Activity

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference("my_checkbox");

   checkboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {            

   public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

          boolean myValue = (Boolean) newValue;

          if(myValue)
                  startService(new Intent(Settings.this, MyService.class));
          else
                  stopService(new Intent(Settings.this, MyService.class));

         return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this code usable for CheckBox? Because I'm using CheckBox, not CheckBoxPreference.

Comment: Use findViewById for the Checkbox in your layout. Should work in the same way. Minor edits only.

Comment: getPreferenceManager() only usable under PreferenceActivity, I can't use this method here